# Load a component after getting API fetched data in React.js

Tags: reactjs, api, mount

My components code is like below

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.props.dispatch(getCountry());
}


render() {

let rows = this.props.countries.map((item, index) => (//some code here));


return (
      <div>
        {rows ? (
          //components HTML code here
       ) : (
          <img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading ..."/>
        )}
      </div>
)
}
```

But the component is loading before API fetched data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for `rows` data since it would be an empty array if not fetched.

```
return (
      <div>
        {rows && rows.length ? (
          //components HTML code here
       ) : (
          <img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading ..."/>
        )}
      </div>
)
```

You can also write your condition like `rows && rows.length > 0` same with `rows && rows.length`. The`rows.length` if it's empty will resolved to `0` which is `false`, but if greather than 0 will be `true`(Typecasting or type conversion).

```
return (
      <div>
        {(rows && rows.length > 0 ? (
          //components HTML code here
       ) : (
          <img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading ..."/>
        )}
      </div>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

`rows` is an array hence `!rows` will still be true. Try this :

```
return (
      <div>
        {rows && rows.length ? (
          //components HTML code here
       ) : (
          <img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading ..."/>
        )}
      </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `componentWillUnmount() {
        this.props.countries = []
      }`, That might help you.